# alias 'it' in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write some tests (not for code coverage, but irrelevant here) in rspec for a ROR app and need to alias describe and it, at the least. I can alias describe just fine because it's at the top level. But, I can't get anything else to work. like this guy:

```
module RSpec
  module Core
    class ExampleGroupMethods
      alias :they :it
    end
  end
end
```

I included that in the spec file but I am not getting the module path right. I looked over the rspec codebase but am hitting a wall so I don't think I quite know what I'm doing. Any tips or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to use [`alias_example_to`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration%3aalias_example_to):

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.alias_example_to :they
end
```

This is part of the public API of RSpec.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to use [define_example_method](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L70-93). This is how RSpec defines the example group methods like `it` and `specify` which are all really just aliases of each other. Not sure if there's an approved API for tapping into it, but you should be able to do something like:

```
module RSpec
  module Core
    class ExampleGroupMethods
      class << self
        define_example_method :they
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that last night but wasn't sure it really did what it looked like it did, but guess I was right. However i tried that and get "undefined method `define_example_method' for #<Class:RSpec::Core::ExampleGroupMethods> (NoMethodError)" which is the same brick wall I always seem to hit. It LOOKS like it should work but I don't understand why it's not.

Comment: Where are you putting this code and are you requiring rspec-core anywhere before it?