# is there a way to alias `describe` .. `it` to `di` in ruby / rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec2

As I understand it, rspec requires both:

```
describe '...' do
  it '...' do 
  end
end
```

I'd like to shorten this syntax to like:

```
di '...' do

end
```

for one-off specs. I have seen this [alias 'it' in rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317558/alias-it-in-rspec) but this is just for aliasing the example method.

Is there any way to do this? Or something shorter for one-off specs? Can I set this globally?

thx

Comment: Hi Tim, Was there something else you were looking for in the way of answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really an alias, but you can define a `di` method to do what you want as follows:

```
def di(example, &block)
  describe example do
    it &block
  end
end
```

You can make it globally available as a "helper method" by following the documentation at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module.

Comment: thx Peter, that sounds good - I was thinking something like that.