# Is there an alternative to "it" in RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Some RSpec methods have aliases for how you phrase them e.g. `describe` and `context` both do the same thing.

It's not always useful to start a spec statement with `it` - are there any alternatives to how one can phrase that part of the test?

e.g. it might be nice to phrase the following:

```
context "when copying a Page object" do
  expect_that "the image gets copies" do 
    ...
  end
end
```

Are there aliases for `it` that one can use?

Comment: This might help: [alias 'it' in rspec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317558/alias-it-in-rspec)

Answer (score 4):

`specify` is a [minimally documented](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it) synonym for `it`. `example` is also a synonym, but I'm not aware of any documentation.

There's also `its`, which has been factored out to a [separate gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-its/versions/1.0.0.pre) as of RSpec 3.0.

Comment: May be worth take a look at the code: [example definitions method names](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L151).